# How to stop notification sound from playing three times?

Tags: notifications, settings, operating-system, custom-sounds

I noticed several years ago after getting a new phone that newer versions of the Android software seem to play my notification sound three times. Prior to this phone it only ever played once. It gets pretty annoying and I was wondering if there's any way to configure this so the sound only plays once? Or is this hard-coded?

It has happened with my last three phones, so it's likely a feature of newer versions of the Android software. I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 running Android 7.1.1.

Whenever I get a notification sound (custom WAV sound that is just the door chime from Star Trek TNG playing once) for an email, app, etc, instead of just playing once, it plays three times in a row.

I have not been able to locate any settings that would allow me to configure how many times it plays.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, I had this problem.  I just checked my Star Trek Chime file, and the file contains the chime three times.  Whoops.  Try a different custom sound.  The whistle file I got from the same website just whistles once.